# Keep slider elements on the same row with position relative

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a slider with 3 slides for now. I want those 3 slides to be on the same rows or to be moved to the same row without `position: absolute`.

Live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5z167ypt

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active-slide">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-right">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-right">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
</div><!-- .slider -->

<div class="controlers">
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
</div><!-- .controlers -->
```

CSS:

```
.slider,
.controlers{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 1s transform ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-left{
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.slide-right{
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}
```

jQuery:

```
//On clicking #next button
$('#next').click(function(){
    var current = $('.active-slide'),
        next = $('.active-slide').next();

  //Move current active slide to the left & remove active class
  current.removeClass('active-slide').addClass('slide-left');

  //Add active class to nect slide to be in the center & remove slide classes
  next.addClass('active-slide').removeClass('slide-right slide-left');
});

//On clicking #previous button
$('#previous').click(function(){
    var current = $('.active-slide'),
        previous = $('.active-slide').prev();
      
  //Move current active slide to the right & remove active class
  current.removeClass('active-slide').addClass('slide-right');

  //Add active class to previous slide to be in the center & remove slide classes
  previous.addClass('active-slide').removeClass('slide-right slide-left');
});
```

For now, The 3 slides are divided into 3 rows. Each slide is moving right and left in a separate row. I want all the 3 slides to be moving in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for slider. Like [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"/>

$('.slider').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: true,
dots: true,
});
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide active-slide">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-right">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-right">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae reiciendis maiores quia excepturi doloribus fugit nemo in inventore quidem at modi quasi rerum nulla ut, ab libero adipisci sint dolores.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```